# How to store a set of behavioral rules?

Tags: data-structures, game-ai, behavior-tree

I have this idea in my head to create a game where the player creates a bot and defines its behavior. The bot is then sent to an open world (a very simplistic one) and has to survive as long as possible.

Currently I'm trying to figure out the correct data format, in which I would store the behavior definition. Any advice?

The behavior should be defined as a simple set of conditions and actions. I'm thinking of some sort of tree structure where the inner nodes would be conditions and leaves would represent actions, but I'm having difficulties with comming up with something actually usable.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Look into "Behavior Trees".

It's the industry standard nowadays, and you can check out a free-of-charge, and state of the art implementation provided with Unreal Engine 4. They also have a ton of tutorials and YouTube videos on the subject.

Good luck